# Node Js Application host in openshift

Tags: node.js, git, openshift

OpenShift is Red Hat's Platform-as-a-Service (PaaS) that allows developers to quickly develop, host, and scale applications in a cloud environment. With OpenShift you have a choice of offerings, including online, on premise, and open source project options.
I am trying to host my application in openshift. It gives an error when i add git repository to the request.

```
HAProxy instance is started
HAProxy instance is started
The initial build for the application failed: Shell command '/sbin/runuser -s /bin/sh 56540dff7628e1120c000006 -c "exec /usr/bin/runcon 'unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c5,c81' /bin/sh -c \"gear postreceive --init >> /tmp/initial-build.log 2>&1\""' returned an error. rc=255

.Last 10 kB of build output:
Stopping NodeJS cartridge
Repairing links for 1 deployments
Saving away previously installed Node modules
Building git ref 'master', commit a601415
Building NodeJS cartridge
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@1.4.28
npm info using node@v0.10.35
npm info preinstall JsFBApps@0.0.0
npm info build /var/lib/openshift/56540dff7628e1120c000006/app-root/runtime/repo
npm info linkStuff JsFBApps@0.0.0
npm info install JsFBApps@0.0.0
npm info postinstall JsFBApps@0.0.0
npm info prepublish JsFBApps@0.0.0
npm info ok 
Preparing build for deployment
Deployment id is 023a0c45
Activating deployment
HAProxy already running
Starting NodeJS cartridge
Tue Nov 24 2015 02:15:34 GMT-0500 (EST): Starting application 'jsfbapps' ...
Waiting for application port (8080) become available ...
Application 'jsfbapps' failed to start (port 8080 not available)
-------------------------
Git Post-Receive Result: failure
Activation status: failure
Activation failed for the following gears:
56540dff7628e1120c000006 (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/56540dff7628e1120c000006/nodejs
#<IO:0x00000000ebd2a0>
#<IO:0x00000000ebd228>
)
Deployment completed with status: failure
postreceive failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show me your code how you are setting ip and port for listening.

Please use below code if you are using express framework:

```
var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, ipaddress, function() {
    // Do your stuff
});
```

You need to use IP and Port, defined by OpenShift and Specified in its Enviorment Variable.

process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP

process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT

https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-environment-variables.html

Comment: thanks for the response. yeah i used express framework. These lines should be added to the "www.js" . Am i correct? Do you know any sample application on github for this.

Comment: if you paste your code for www.js i will make change for you

Comment: [link](https://github.com/tharinda221/JsFBApps/blob/master/bin/www) this is my www.js file can you please tell where to put this...

Comment: Line 15 : var port = normalizePort(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || '8080');

Comment: Line 28 : var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";    server.listen(port, ipaddress);

Comment: I added those lines.. but still got the same error :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96060/discussion-between-tharinda-ehelepola-and-hiren-s).